# How to center divs vertically inside table cells

Tags: html, css

I know that's been asked many times and I am trying to compile the answers but cannot come up with something that would work for me. Here is my code:

```
 <div style="position:relative; overflow:hidden; height:35px">
            <table style="width:100%; height:100%;">
                <tr>
                    <td style="vertical-align:middle;">
                        <div style="float:left">
                            <img src="image1.png">
                            <img src="image2.png">
                        </div>
                        <div style="float:right;height:30px" class="panel panel-default">
                            <img src="image3.png">
                        </div>
                        <div style="float:right;width:250px;height:30px" class="panel panel-default"></div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/0nuq7up2/)**

What I want is to have all inner divs aligned vertically in the middle.
Can someone please help?

Thanks

Comment: I'm afraid that no. We can't not help You out if you don't make a better question adding an example (as a jsfiddle) of what you are really looking for (with real images). We often read minds and future codes but sometimes we fail.

Comment: Demo added (with real images :) ). What's with the 35px height on the wrapper div?

Comment: Also, what's the table for? You have but one cell, and you're not using it to any apparent effect.

Comment: First step, remove the floats.

Comment: Aaaaand... you seem to be using Bootstrap classes. Is Bootstrap in play?

Comment: Here's how I'd do it. Tables are for data, not layout. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/0nuq7up2/1/

Comment: Yes, I am using Bootstrap classes. I was wondering if there are tools out there to build Bootstrap layouts.

Answer (score 0):

You should use inline-block

```
<style>
    .my_div {position:relative; overflow:hidden; height:35px;}
    .my_div table {width:100%; height:100%;}
    .my_td div {display: inline-block; vertical-align:middle;}
</style>

<div class="my_div">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="my_td">
                <div>
                    <img src="image1.png">
                    <img src="image2.png">
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <img src="image3.png">
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: That doesn't look anything I need.